# ATMEGA 32A PU signature

Tags: atmega

What is the signature of ATmega32A PU? I couldn't find it in the datasheet or Atmel's site. Is it same as ATMEGA32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 250 (section 26.3) of the [full ATmega32A datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8155-8-bit-Microcontroller-AVR-ATmega32A_Datasheet.pdf):

[image: datasheet exceprt]

The "PU" designation is a suffix for ordering purposes, detailed on page 320. The "PU" just refers to the 40P6 package, which in turn is a 40-pin through hole version.

If you compare the ATmega32A to the [ATmega32](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf) (without the "A"), the signature is the same. The "A" revision is a replacement version with power consumption optimizations. Atmel has [a guide specifically for migrating from the ATmega32 to the ATmega32A](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8162.pdf).